# Access kafka headers in rpc replies using faust streamming

Tags: faust

Is it possible to access kafka headers in the faust rpc replies?
Here is example of two faust agents. One (the `pow`) calls another (`mul`) and receive a result as a value. But how to know the kafka headers in the reply topic?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from typing import AsyncIterable
import faust
from faust import StreamT

app = faust.App('RPC99', reply_create_topic=True)
pow_topic = app.topic('RPC__pow')
mul_topic = app.topic('RPC__mul')

@app.agent(pow_topic)
async def pow(stream: StreamT[float]) -> AsyncIterable[float]:
    async for value in stream:
        yield await mul.ask(value=value ** 2)
        # Headers for the returning result here?

@app.agent(mul_topic)
async def mul(stream: StreamT[float]) -> AsyncIterable[float]:
    async for value in stream:
        yield value * 100.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the header from the event which is received from:

> stream.events()

```
@app.agent(topic)
async def iterrate(stream):
    async for event in stream.events():
        value = event.value
        offset = event.message.offset
        headers = event.headers
```

definition for faust.types.events:

https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/faust.types.events.html#faust.types.events.EventT

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the stream events have an attribute that is `headers` of type `Union[List[Tuple[str, bytes]]`.

The [docs](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/faust.events.html#faust.events.Event.headers) have it here but they're not terribly detailed on that point at the moment.

It looks like you can do something like

```
@app.agent(topic)
async def process(stream):
    async for value in stream:
        do_something(value.headers)
```

If you've already deserialized the message it looks like you can also access the raw event with the [streams api](https://github.com/robinhood/faust/issues/376#issuecomment-507690006) via `faust.streams.current_event()`.

Edit in response to Роман's comment:

It looks like you have to explicitly send the message in order to modify the headers. Look at the function signature for `send()` over in the [channel api](https://faust.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/faust/channels.html). I think `send` or one of the other variations of send in that class should be what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, I know I can access them from stream.events() or using current_event(). But these states for the incoming message. I'm asking about the reply.

Comment: The `ask()` method has `headers` too